# How to get Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpContext instance in Class Constructor using DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building a throwaway application in MVC 6 and experimenting with different architectures for dependencies.

The problem I am facing is how to create a custom '`MyAppContext`' object specific to the Application.  This would require some information from the `HttpContext` and some information from the database, and will be a request-scoped repository for application specific attributes.  I want to pass the instance of the `HttpContext` into the constructor of the '`MyAppContext`'.

I have successfully created a '`DataService`' object with an `IDataService` interface using DI and this works Ok.
The difference with the 'MyAppContext' class is that it has two parameters in the constructor - the '`DataService`' and the `Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpContext`.  Here is the MyAppContext class:

```
public class MyAppContext : IMyAppContext
{
    public MyAppContext(IDataService dataService, HttpContext httpContext)
    {
       //do stuff here with the httpContext
    }
}
```

In the startup code, I register the DataService instance and the MyAppContext instance:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        //adds a singleton instance of the DataService using DI
        services.AddSingleton<IDataService, DataService>();
        services.AddScoped<IMyAppContext, MyAppContext>();    

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseErrorPage();
        app.UseRequestServices();
        app.UseMvc(routes => /* routes stuff */);
    }
```

I am expecting the `HttpContext` parameter in the constructor to get resolved by DI.
When running the code, this is the exception I get returned:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpContext' while attempting to activate 'MyAppContext'

I figure this is because there is no specific instance of `HttpContext` that this error is occurring, but I don't know how to register the `HttpContext` instance in DI.  I added the line '`app.UseRequestServices();`' but this hasn't made any difference.  I also tried a variant of:

```
services.AddScoped<HttpContext, HttpContext>();
```

But this fails because the second `HttpContext` is supposed to be an instance - I know it's not correct but haven't been able to work out what is.

So, in summary - how can I pass in the `HttpContext` object into the constructor of MyAppContext?

Comment: HttpContext.Current?

Comment: This should work if you are using Simple injector
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600678/simple-injector-how-to-inject-httpcontext][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600678/simple-injector-how-to-inject-httpcontext

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28973242/1184056

Comment: possible duplicate of [How properly inject HttpContext in MVC6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970140/how-properly-inject-httpcontext-in-mvc6)

Comment: I found that a controller, apparently from inhereting from Controller, has access to HttpContect and was able to pass this to my service when needed. _myService.PassTheUser(HttpContext.User)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Inject `IHttpContextAccessor` in the constructor

Comment: Yes, this works.  Specifically its the Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.IHttpContextAccessor type, which then provides the .Value property containing the HttpContext.

Answer (score 19):

By injecting an `HttpContext` into your component you are violating the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29). To be more specifically, you are violating:

- The [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (DIP) because you depend on a framework type (the `HttpContext`).
- The [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (ISP) because the `HttpContext` has many methods, while the consumer never uses them all.

Both violations make it much harder to test your code. Although you can instead inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` as @victor suggests, this is still a violation of both the DIP and ISP, because this is an abstraction that is provided by the framework and you still depend on HttpContext. According to the DIP it is the client who should define the abstraction. This causes your code to be needlessly coupled to the framework.

Instead you should strive to specify narrow role interfaces; interfaces that do one specific thing for you that is specific to the needs of your application. Injecting a big dictionary with string values (as what `HttpContext` is, is never very specific). From your question it's unclear what kind of data you need from our `MyAppContext`, but I expect something like information of the currently logged in user. For this you can define a specific `IUserContext` abstraction, for instance:

```
public interface IUserContext {
    IPrincipal CurrentUser { get; }
}
```

An adapter that connects the application to the ASP.NET framework can be easily created for this abstraction:

```
sealed class AspNetUserContextAdapter : IUserContext  {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;
    public AspNetUserContextAdapter(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }
    public IPrincipal CurrentUser => accessor.HttpContext.User;
}
```

This adapter does depend on `IHttpContextAccessor`, but this is okay, since the adapter is an infrastructural component located in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). There are serveral ways to register this class, for instance:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserContext, AspNetUserContext>();
```

Comment: I instinctively knew that binding directly to HttpContext was incorrect, I was expecting to find an interface to use (which is what IHttpContextAccessor is).   The application has no purpose, I'm just exploring these issues by way of practical example.  I understand the example shown - the only concern I have with this type is that by not using an IHttpContextAccessor (or similar) you would have to keep going back and redefining the constructor parameters each time you discovered new requirements.  (first it's the user, then the querystring, then the request headers, etc).

Comment: @BruceChapman: if you find yourself having to go back "and redifining the constructor parameters each time you discovered new requirements", that might indicate a Single Responsibility Principle violation. That `IUserContext` abstraction should never do anything else than getting the current user. If you need data from the query string etc, you are probably getting different information and this deserves an abstraction on its own. The hard part of course is getting your abstractions right, but it usually gets much easier if you start by sticking to the basic principles (the SOLID principles).

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` is gone in vNext

Comment: HttpContext is an abstract class, not a concrete type.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde: [Nope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The class is even marked with the `sealed` keyword.

Comment: @Steven please explain to me which part of HttpContext is marked as `sealed`. https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/HttpContext.cs

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde: I'm sorry, I was too quick. Things have changed; HttpContext is indeed abstract now in Core. That doesn't change the fact though that DIP is violated. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Am I missing something? 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current'

Comment: @NathanHartley: You are right, there is no static `Current` property on `HttpContext` in ASP.NET Core. I'm not sure what went wrong here. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the startup class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{        
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddMvcCore();
}
```

In the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core;

private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public ServerSentEventController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Why would you pass the HttpContext in the constructor?
Why not directly access it wherever you want?

```
public MyAppContext(IDataService dataService)
    {
       HttpContext mycontext = HttpContext.Current;
       //do stuff here with mycontext
    }
```

Comment: That's the kind of class dependency I am trying to avoid by using DI.  That type of code embeds a dependency within the class and it's not clear where the HttpContext reference comes from.

Comment: This just doesn't work in ASP.NET 5. And is also a pretty bad idea in MVC 5/4/3 applications.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` has been removed in vNext