# Asp.net core DI with context

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying implement a simple dependency (in ASP.NET Core) as this:

```
public partial class BaseController : Controller
{
    public new ITempDataDictionary TempData { get; private set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);

        //preparação da tempdata
        this.TempData = new TempDataDictionary(HttpContext); //todo: DI?
        this.TempData.Load();
    }
}
```

}

The problem is the fact `TempDataDictionary` depends of `HttpContext` present in this controller.
How to implement that scenario in DI, since the `ServiceLocator` has no knowledge of `HttpContext` at Startup?

As this?

services.AddScoped(); //??????

But where i fill the constructor parameter `HttpContext` if this present just in controller?

Comment: Prevent letting your application components take a direct dependency on `HttpContext`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055268/how-to-get-microsoft-aspnet-http-httpcontext-instance-in-class-constructor-using/30057522#30057522)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a service to handle your state data and add it as scoped.

```
public class AppStateService
{ 
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private IDictionary<string, object> _data;
    public AppStateService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider, UserManager<EntsogUser> userManager, CompanyRepository companyRepository)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _data = _tempDataProvider.LoadTempData(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext);
    }

    private void SetValue(string name, object value)
    {
        _data[name] = value;
        _tempDataProvider.SaveTempData(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext,_data);
    }

    private object GetValue(string name)
    {

        if (!_data.ContainsKey(name))
            return null;
        return _data[name];
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs (ConfigureServices)

```
services.AddScoped<AppStateService>();
```

In your controller

```
public class TestController : Controller
{

    protected readonly CompanyRepository _companyRepository;

    public TariffsController(AppStateService appStateService)
    {
        _appStateService = appStateService;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take a dependency on IHttpContextAccessor and register it with DI

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

then use it to get the HttpContext

However in a controller you have direct access to HttpContext so it isn't clear to me why you would want to inject it there